# Cell For Row At Index Path Confusion

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a cell that either displays a string post or a image post but when I add another object to my array that contains the data for the cells, the images in the image posts are duplicated on the tableView. I think I did something wrong in the cellForRowAtIndex path method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
postObject *currentPost = [self.postArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
self.cell = (storyboardCell *) [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

if (currentPost.imagePost == nil) {
    _cell.personStringPost.text = currentPost.postString;
}
if (currentPost.imagePost != nil) {
    _cell.personImagePost.image = currentPost.imagePost;
    _cell.personStringPost.hidden = true;
}
[self changeToCircle:_cell.profileImage];
_cell.profileImage.image = currentPost.profileImage;

[_cell.nameLabel setTitle:currentPost.nameString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_cell.eventLabel setTitle:currentPost.eventString forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[_cell.profileImageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(profilePage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_cell.nameLabel addTarget:self action:@selector(profilePage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_cell.eventLabel addTarget:self action:@selector(eventPage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_cell.likePage addTarget:self action:@selector(likePage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_cell.comment addTarget:self action:@selector(commentPage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
_cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

return _cell;
```

}

Comment: Please log your `self.postArray` and post its contents.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is due to cell reuse.  When you scroll, the tableView keeps the cells for rows that go off screen, and reuses them when you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`.  If they previously had an image, it will still be there.  If so, you need to remove it.  Likewise, if personStringPost was previously hidden, it still will be.  I would also avoid using self.cell or _cell; declare a local variable instead.  Amend your code as follows:

```
postObject *currentPost = [self.postArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
StoryboardCell *cell = (storyboardCell *) [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

if (currentPost.imagePost == nil) {
    cell.personStringPost.text = currentPost.postString;
    cell.personStringPost.hidden = false;
    cell.personImagePost.image = nil;
}
if (currentPost.imagePost != nil) {
    cell.personImagePost.image = currentPost.imagePost;
    cell.personStringPost.hidden = true;
    cell.personStringPost.text = @""; 
}
[self changeToCircle:cell.profileImage];
cell.profileImage.image = currentPost.profileImage;

[cell.nameLabel setTitle:currentPost.nameString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.eventLabel setTitle:currentPost.eventString forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[cell.profileImageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(profilePage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.nameLabel addTarget:self action:@selector(profilePage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.eventLabel addTarget:self action:@selector(eventPage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.likePage addTarget:self action:@selector(likePage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.comment addTarget:self action:@selector(commentPage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

return cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you should try below code.

if (currentPost.imagePost == nil) {

```
     _cell.personStringPost.text = currentPost.postString;
     _cell.personStringPost.hidden = FALSE;
```

} else {

```
     _cell.personStringPost.hidden = TRUE;
```

}

if (currentPost.imagePost != nil) {

```
     _cell.personImagePost.image = currentPost.imagePost;
     _cell.personImagePost.hidden = false;
```

} else {

```
     _cell.personImagePost.image = nil;
     _cell.personImagePost.hidden = true;
```

}